# Which type of fliter should be designed to remove 50 Hz

Tags: matlab

Actually I am using DSP kit TMS320C6711 through which I want to remove 50Hz component out of the signal. I am unable to interface Code Composer studio (v2) with matlab. Therefore, I have designed FIR notch filter using Code composer Studio in which coefficients are taken from fdatool of matlab. Kaiser window has been used for filtering. The problem I am facing here is when lower and upper cutoff frequencies are 35Hz and 65Hz respectively only I am able to manage significant attenuation. When I am trying to get the cutoff frequencies closer, attenuation level is reducing to unsatisfactory levels.
So, please help me to decide the window to be used and order to be selected so that I could achieve significant attenuation of 50Hz component with sharp cutoff frequencies.

Comment: An IIR type notch filter would normally achieve better selectivity and greater attenuation but comes with the risk of instability.

Comment: What's your sampling frequency?

Comment: 8000 samples per second

Comment: As @Deve pointed out, the IIR would attain the selectivity you want, but it also comes with a non-linear phase response. This might matter/not matter depending on your application though.

Answer (score 2):

Highly selective notch filters require a rather long impulse response, which makes FIR an inefficient approach. A simple IIR notch filter is easily designed by zero/pole placement:

Take a 2nd order recursive filter and place two zeros at $\exp(i \omega_0)$ and $\exp(-i \omega_0)$ on the unit circle, where $\omega_0=2\pi\frac{f}{f_s}$ is the normalised center frequency of your notch. Then place two poles just inside the unit circle behind the zeros, namely at $r\exp(i\omega_0)$ and $r\exp(-i\omega_0)$ with $0<r<1$. These two poles will cancel the effect of the zeros beyond a certain distance. The closer the poles are to the zeros (i.e. the closer $r$ is to $1$), the sharper the notch will be. Picking the right $r$ therefore controls your bandwidth but also gives you the ability to control numerical stability and error accumulation for limited precision implementations. If you more the poles too close to the unit circle, the filter will start to behave weirdly.

Using this recipe to calculate your filter coefficients we can directly start with the z-domain transfer function
$$H(z) = \frac{\left(z-\exp(i\omega_0)\right)\left(z-\exp(-i\omega_0)\right)}{\left(z-r\exp(i\omega_0)\right)\left(z-r\exp(-i\omega_0)\right)}$$
which can be expanded to
$$H(z)=\frac{z^2-z\left(\exp(i\omega_0)+\exp(-i\omega_0)\right)+1}{z^2-z r\left(\exp(i\omega_0)+\exp(-i\omega_0) \right)+r^2}=\frac{z^2-2\cos(\omega_0)z+1}{z^2-2r\cos(\omega_0)z+r^2}$$
and cancelling $z^2$ gives you the transfer function in terms of unit delays:
$$H(z) = \frac{1-2\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}+z^{-2}}{1-2r\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}+r^2z^{-2}} $$
Using the definition of the transfer function $H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$ for input and output signal z-transforms $X(z)$ and $Y(z)$ respectively results in the z-transform of the filter recursion:
$$Y(z)\left(1-2r\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}+r^2z^{-2} \right)=X(z)\left(1-2\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}+z^{-2} \right)$$
Inverting the z-transform takes us to discrete time domain:
$$y[n]-2r\cos(\omega_0)y[n-1]+r^2y[n-2]=x[n]-2\cos(\omega_0)x[n-1]+x[n-2]$$
Finally, we can solve for the output signal at time $n$ and get the recursive filter equation
$$y[n]=x[n]-2\cos(\omega_0)x[n-1]+x[n-2]+2r\cos(\omega_0)y[n-1]-r^2y[n-2]$$
This equation gives you the most recent output sample in terms of the three most recent input samples and the prior two output samples. As initial condition you can assume that all recent samples are 0.